# как в google maps добавить onclick

Tags: php, javascript, yii2, bootstrap

дело в том что при написании адреса на карте сразу показывает маркер с координатами и с маршрутом, и я хотел бы добавить обработчик типа кнопки чтобы при нажатии был построен маршрут, а вот и сам код:

```
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'location')->textInput()->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'address', [
                            'template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{error}"])->textInput(['required' => 'required'])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Address')) ?>

                        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 807px; height:380px"></div>


                        <br/>

                        <?php

                        $this->registerJs("

                        var cor1 = '$w1';
                        var cor2 = '$w2';
                        console.log('cor1:'+cor1);
                        console.log('cor2:'+cor2);

                          var geocoder;
                          var map;
                          var marker;
                          var markers = [];

                    function initialize(){

                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cor1, cor2);
                        var options = {
                            zoom: 10,
                            center: latlng,
                        };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,     
                            map: map
                        });
                        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    }

                      function DeleteMarkers() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        markers[i].setMap(null);
                            }
                            markers = [];
                        }

                    function findLocation(val){



        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true, suppressInfoWindows: true } );

                        geocoder.geocode( {'address': val}, function(results, status) {

                        var location = results[0].geometry.location
                        map.setCenter(location)
                        map.setZoom(15)
                        DeleteMarkers()

                        $('#show-location').val(location)
                        console.log('location:'+location);

                         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            draggable: true,
                            position: location
                        });

                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function()
                    {
                                $('#show-location').val(marker)                                     
                    });
        var start_point = new google.maps.LatLng(cor1, cor2);
        var end_point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat123, long123);    

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: start_point,
            map: map
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: end_point,
            map: map,
             draggable: false,
        });     

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });         

        var request = {
         origin: start_point,
         destination: end_point,
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
         unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
         provideRouteAlternatives: true,
         avoidHighways: false,
         avoidTolls: true
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
          var routes = result.routes;
          var leg = routes[0].legs;
          var lenght = leg[0].distance.text;
          var duration = leg[0].duration.text;
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: 'Дистанция: '+lenght+'<br>Продолжительность: '+duration });
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
        }
        );
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
                    console.log('e1'+a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4));
                    console.log('e2'+a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4));
                                        });
                    })
                    var massiv = $('#show-location').val();
                    var masar = massiv.split(',');
                    var lat123 = masar[0].replace('(',''); 
                    var long123 = masar[1].replace(')',''); 
                    console.log('ken' +lat123);
                    console.log('rat' +long123);

                    }

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                        initialize();

                        if( $('#show-address').val()){
                         _location = $('#show-address').val()
                           findLocation(_location)
                           }

                        $('#show-address').bind('blur keyup',function(){
                           _location = $('#show-address').val()
                           findLocation(_location)

                        })
                    });"
```

Comment: Что должно стать кликабельным? Что должно происходить после клика?

Comment: тут у меня при вводе адреса выводиться точка и сразу путь к нему, но я хотел бы чтобы путь к нему построился после нажатия кнопки, я пытался добавить функцию и передать значение но увы ничего не происходит